# Can EventArgs ever be null?

Tags: c#, .net, events

I have `protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)` in some of my code and code analysis gives a CA1062 because I don't check if `e` is null.

Convention is that `EventArgs` should never be null; that's why we have `EventArgs.Empty`. Sure, I could be stupid and pass `null` instead of `EventArgs.Empty` when raising some event, but here it will be some auto-generated code that will be raising the FormClosing event so I just suppressed the warning.

Are there some corner cases that could cause EventArgs to be null by the framework and not caused by the programmer?

Comment: `EventArgs` is a reference type and there's no protection in C# against `null` values on reference types.

Comment: [CA1062](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182182.aspx) is generic warning, you can disable/ignore it in case **you** never pass `null` (because you can subclass form and rise event yourself, etc.). *Standard* [tag:winforms] events handlers should never receive  `null`.

Comment: it should not be null because in the first place, it will only be triggered when the event happens, so we are sure that the event fires and we expect that instance of that event in our listener

Comment: EventArgs.Empty is a default argument but think of it if the event requires no arguments then why add them? If you use empty you could just as well have used null. Maybe refactor such that you don't have arguments at all. Or such that there are always valid arguments.

Comment: @Desperado huh? that makes absolutely no sense!

Comment: @ardila move on anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: yes, you can do this:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    OnFormClosing(null);
}
```

But unless you actually do something like this, you can ignore the warning.

Looking at the source code for class Form, we can find [this method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Windows.Forms/R/7c52f639802c2e15.html), which resumes to this:

```
    /// <devdoc>
    ///    <para>Raises the FormClosing event for this form when Application.Exit is called.
    ///          Returns e.Cancel returned by the event handler.</para>
    /// </devdoc>
    internal bool RaiseFormClosingOnAppExit() {
        FormClosingEventArgs e = new FormClosingEventArgs(CloseReason.ApplicationExitCall, false);
        OnFormClosing(e);
        return e.Cancel;
    }
```

So no, there is no way `e` will be null when the event is raised by WinForms.

Comment: but event listeners should not be called like this :3

Comment: I believe another case when this is possible is subclassing (event risers are protected and can be overridden, where you can rise event with `null`)

Comment: Yeah, sure. But I meant some corner case caused by winforms itself, not some crap I wrote.

Comment: Then very likely not, passing EventArgs.Empty is the convention. not null

Comment: I have always wrapped my event handlers in an "OnDoSomething" style. Check if the handler is null and execute only then.